# How to update only one table for model from database?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to add just one table without updating the entire database edmx model with entity framework 6?

I have a new table in the database, but I don't know how to add only it but not update the entire edmx.

I tested Huagati, but this not work with VS2019

Comment: drag and drop the new table. but note it will update the auto generated code. if you really wrote something in auto generated class and don't wanted to modify it. then try to move the code from there first . it always gonna be a problem

Comment: @AvinashReddy When you say to drag and drop the table inside you say to drag and drop the .cs file?

Comment: Go to=> Server Explorer and connect to the db click hold on table. and drag to the diagram you should be able to release it.

Comment: When I click and drag on the table, the mouse is locked. Not allowing me to drag and drop on the diagram @AvinashReddy